# replacing args in docker file is not working

Tags: docker

I have the following docker file

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

# CAMUNDA VARIABLES
ARG VERSION=7.12.0
ARG DISTRO=tomcat
ARG SNAPSHOT=false
ARG EE=true

#Understand difference between ARG and ENV:
#https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/

#AZURE SQL VARIABLES, DEFAULT SETTINS ARE DEV DB Environment
#Be sure database and tables are created upfront
#Use docker build . -t xx/camundawithbasicdev
#Use docker build . -t xx/camundawithbasicauthqa --build-arg SQLSERVER=a_value DBPASSWORD=a_value DBUSERNAME=a_value
#Use docker build . -t xx/camundawithbasicauthprod --build-arg some_variable_name=a_value
#And replace variables as needed.

ARG SQLSERVER=xx
ARG DBPASSWORD=Hxx
ARG DBUSERNAME=xx
ARG DATABASENAME=xx


RUN apk add --no-cache \
        ca-certificates \
        maven \
        tar \
        wget \
        xmlstarlet

COPY settings.xml download.sh camunda-tomcat.sh camunda-wildfly.sh  /tmp/

RUN /tmp/download.sh

#Enable Basic AUTH
COPY web.xml /camunda/webapps/engine-rest/WEB-INF/web.xml 

##### FINAL IMAGE #####

FROM alpine:3.10

ARG VERSION=7.12.0

ENV CAMUNDA_VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV DB_DRIVER=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
ENV DB_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://${SQLSERVER}.database.windows.net:1433;database=${DATABASENAME};user=${DBUSERNAME};password={DBPASSWORD};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
ENV DB_USERNAME=${DBUSERNAME}
ENV DB_PASSWORD=${DBPASSWORD}
ENV DB_CONN_MAXACTIVE=20
ENV DB_CONN_MINIDLE=5
ENV DB_CONN_MAXIDLE=20
ENV DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW=true
ENV DB_VALIDATION_QUERY="SELECT 1"
ENV SKIP_DB_CONFIG=
ENV WAIT_FOR=
ENV WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT=120
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV DEBUG=TRUE
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
ENV JMX_PROMETHEUS=false

EXPOSE 8080 8000

# Downgrading wait-for-it is necessary until this PR is merged
# https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/pull/68
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        openjdk11-jre-headless \
        tzdata \
        tini \
        xmlstarlet \
    && wget -O  /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh \
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/a454892f3c2ebbc22bd15e446415b8fcb7c1cfa4/wait-for-it.sh" --no-check-certificate \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S camunda && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S camunda -G camunda -h /camunda -s /bin/bash -D camunda


# end ssh config
WORKDIR /camunda
USER camunda

#MSSQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER INSTALL
COPY mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar /camunda/lib/


ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD "./camunda.sh" 

COPY --chown=camunda:camunda --from=builder /camunda .
```

However when I run the image, it looks like the variables are not replaced on the connection string part

what am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean `DB_URL` contains the literal text `${SQLSERVER}`, or do you mean something else?

Comment: BTW, a reproducer that anyone can run themselves to see the problem would be a lot easier to work with here. Ideally, it could be only about four lines: `FROM alpine:3.10`; `ARG SQLSERVER=xx`; `ENV DB_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://${SQLSERVER}`; `CMD "echo $DB_URL"`, or somesuch -- providing code others can run, expected output, and actual output makes it much easier to test answers. See the [mre] guidelines in the Help Center.

Comment: at the top, you  see XX as variable values, obviously I cant paste my credentials here, but when I run the container, the variables are NOT replaced , I basically get this error:   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host .database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: ".database.windows.net..  Which means that the variable is not replaced, makes sense?

Comment: I don't ask you to paste your credentials; `xx` is fine, as long as you give us code (and a description of actual and desired output of that code) that lets us distinguish whether the `xx` was replaced or not *as part of the question itself*. What's important is that the code is something people who are not you can run, and is the *shortest possible thing that reproduces the error*, as the MRE rules require.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the arguments on a different stage. As far as I know, it's not possible to pass them between stages. For example:

This won't work

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

ARG TEST1=1234

FROM alpine:3.10
ENV TEST2=blablah-${TEST1}
```

if you print TEST2 you'll get `blablah-`

This will:

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

ARG TEST1=1234


FROM alpine:3.10
ARG TEST1=98765
ENV TEST2=blablah-${TEST1}
```

if you print TEST2 you'll get `blahblah-98765

However, I would strongly advice against this way as it'll store your passwords and so on as default env vars in the Docker image you're building. I would pass the connection details when you run docker either with `docker run -e TEST1=1234` or even better, with a docker-compose file.

I would have Dockerfile like this one (very simplified, only with the env vars) Normally, when I need to construct variables like that I do so in the `entrypoint.sh`

So my entrypoint looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DB_URL="jdbc:sqlserver://${SQLSERVER}.database.windows.net:1433;database=${DB_NAME};user=${DB_USERNAME};password=${DB_PASSWORD};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=0;"

echo $DB_URL

echo "Running: '$@'"
exec $@
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

ARG VERSION
ARG DISTRO
ARG SNAPSHOT
ARG EE



FROM alpine:3.10
ARG VERSION

ENV CAMUNDA_VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV DB_DRIVER=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver


ENV DB_CONN_MAXACTIVE=20
ENV DB_CONN_MINIDLE=5
ENV DB_CONN_MAXIDLE=20
ENV DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW=true
ENV DB_VALIDATION_QUERY="SELECT 1"
ENV SKIP_DB_CONFIG=
ENV WAIT_FOR=
ENV WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT=120
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV DEBUG=TRUE
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
ENV JMX_PROMETHEUS=false

RUN apk update && apk add bash

ADD entrypoint.sh / 
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  so-example: 
    image: stackoverflow-example
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - VERSION 
        - DISTRO 
        - SNAPSHOT
    environment:
      - SQLSERVER
      - DB_USERNAME
      - DB_PASSWORD
      - DB_NAME
```

Then, to build the new image I run:

`docker-compose build --build-arg VERSION=7.12.0 --build-arg DISTRO=tomcat --build-arg SNAPSHOT=false --build-arg EE=true`

When I need to run it I export the values I need. For instance:

```
export SQLSERVER=myhost
export DB_USERNAME=db_user
export DB_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
export DB_NAME=mydb
```

And then run it with compose. For example, if I run
`docker-compose run so-example env`

you should see that `DB_URL` is 
`jdbc:sqlserver://myhost.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydb;user=db_user;password=mysecretpassword;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=0;`

I hope this helps

Comment: so moving the args just below the 2nd FROm will do the trick?

Comment: It should, but again, I don't think it's a good idea to store credentials on your image. I'm trying to put together an example on how I would do it

Comment: yeah, that was another question I was going to put, because definitely I dont like the idea of credentials in a docker file

Comment: @LuisValencia updated my answer, I hope this helps you in some way